# SQL - Create View from Multiple Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, left-join

Just wondering, is it possible to create view from multiple views?

I'm trying to create a view (Data_extract_C) from 2 views  (Data_extract_A and Data_Extract_B) by using Left Join. It's been an hour already and it still hasn't finished compiling the result. Is it normal?

Below is the syntax that I'm using.

```
 Create view [TeamA].[Data_Extract_C] as

    select distinct

    [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID, 
    sum ([TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].TotalFilesInput), 
    sum ([TeamA].[Data_Extract_B].TotalFilesOutput)

    from [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A]

    left join 

    [TeamA].[Data_Extract_B] 

    on 

    [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID = [TeamA].[Data_Extract_B].Unique_ID 

    group by [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID

go
```

Thanks all for your help. SQL Server 2012 is really new for me as I usually do data analysis using Excel.

Comment: How much data these tables have?

Comment: Do these views have in index on the join columns?

Comment: Amit, Data_Extract_A has 989200 line items and Data_Extract_B has 207489 line items.

Comment: Sorry Tim, what do you mean the views have in index?

Comment: nested views can get very messy very quickly and indexed view are pretty much selling your soul to the sql-server devil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you really want this:

```
select Unique_ID, 
       sum(TotalFilesInput), 
       sum(TotalFilesOutput)
from ((select a.Unique_ID, a.TotalFilesInput, 0 as TotalFilesOutput
       from [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A] a
      ) union all
      (select b.Unique_ID, 0 as TotalFilesInput, b.TotalFilesOutput
       from [TeamA].[Data_Extract_B] b
      )
     ) ab
group by Unique_ID;
```

Your poor performance is probably caused by a bad `join` -- multiple rows with the same value on both sides.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It's not what I want as the data still scattering everywhere, however it gives me all the calculations correctly. I just need to play with the data in Tableau. So it is possible to create view from multiple views in SQL. Just need to be careful on how to join them together since views are derived from manipulating tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Just wondering, is it possible to create view from multiple views?

Yes it's possible. You can reference views in other views. So your example of creating view out of joining two other views should work.

> It's been an hour already and it still hasn't finished compiling the
>   result. Is it normal?

I'm not sure about this part, i.e. answer is "it depends". Depends on what? Several factors like how large the tables are and how complex the other views ([TeamA].[Data_Extract_A], [TeamA].[Data_Extract_B]) are, what indexes you have (or don't have), etc.

Comment: Thanks Eko for your answer. What do you mean having an index? there are 989200 line items in Data_extract_A and 207489 line items in Data_extract_B.

Answer (score 0):

**Hay Adhitya Sanusi**
try This..

*First Using Join*

```
 CREATE VIEW [TeamA].[Data_Extract_C] 
    as  SELECT 
     [TeamA].Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID, 
    sum ([TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].TotalFilesInput), 
    sum ([TeamA].[Data_Extract_B].TotalFilesOutput)   from 
  [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A] LEFT JOIN [Data_Extract_B]
   [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID = [TeamA].[Data_Extract_B].Unique_ID 
      Group by [TeamA].[Data_Extract_A].Unique_ID
```

*using of UINON*

```
CREATE VIEW myview as


SELECT ... FROM View1......
   UNION
   SELECT ... FROM View2 ....
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is not what I'm looking for.